# Convergence in distribution in more dimensions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence

The general definition of convergence in distribution is given by:
Let $(X^{(n)})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables taking values in a seperable metric space $(S,d)$. We say that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges in distribution to a random variable $X$ if for all $f\in C_b(S)$ we have that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}E\lbrack f(X^{(n)})\rbrack=E\lbrack f(X)\rbrack.
\end{align*}
If we take $S=\mathbb{R}$, this is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(t)=F(t)\text{ for all continuity points }t\in\mathbb{R}\text{ of }F,
\end{align*}
where $F_n$ is the distribution function of $X^{(n)}$ and $F$ is the distribution function of $X$. Does this equivalence hold in the case that $S=\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d\in\mathbb{N}_{>1}$ as well? I.e. is the general definition equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_1^{(n)}\leq t_1,\ldots,X_d^{(n)}\leq t_d)=P(X_1\leq t_1,\ldots,X_d\leq t_d)
\end{align*}
for every continuity point $t\in\mathbb{R}^d$ of $t\mapsto P(X_1\leq t_1,\ldots,X_d\leq t_d)$?

Comment: yes this is equivalent. Try to adapt the proof for $\mathcal S = \mathbb R$.